Increase in AWS S3 bucket size when moved from Standard to Intelligent Access storage class
I have an AWS S3 bucket with objects whose total size is around 5.49 GB. The bucket was in Standard storage class. I moved the bucket from Standard to IA storage class. I see that the bucket size increased by 2kb. What could the reason for this increase in bucket size?
I was expecting the bucket size to remain same.

Are they small objects? If so, you might now be billed for a larger amount of storage. The Amazon S3 pricing page says: "S3 Standard-IA and S3 One Zone-IA storage have a minimum billable object size of 128 KB. Smaller objects may be stored but will be charged for 128 KB of storage at the appropriate storage class rate."

S3 bucket size is based on object size and system metadata.
System metadata is further categorized into

System controlled
User controlled

User controlled metadata contains the information about storage class. So when you changed the storage class it made changes in metadata which resulted in the change in overall size.
